# Support for hardware-accelerated crypto AES on ARMv8 processors running in 32-bit mode?

Tags: aes, cryptographic-hardware

As I understand it, *all* ARM processors based on the 32/64-bit ARMv8-A architecture (and more recent iterations) support [hardware-accelerated AES instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set#Hardware_acceleration_in_other_architectures).

Under Linux, the feature flags in `/proc/cpuinfo` are supposed to [include `aes` for ARM processors which support these instruction](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43539/what-do-the-flags-in-proc-cpuinfo-mean) (also `pmull{2}`, `sha1`, `sha2` for other hardware crypto accelerations).

Many devices with ARMv8-A CPUs are nevertheless built with only 32-bit kernels and userspace, for example the [very common Qualcomm MSM8916 / Snapdragon 410 platform](https://www.reddit.com/r/cyanogenmod/comments/3ndhly/why_are_all_devices_based_on_msm8916_built_on_32/).

I inspected `/proc/cpuinfo` on a rooted MSM8916-based Android device, and to my surprise the CPU is identified as ARMv7 — not ARMv8 — and the `aes` feature is **not** included:

```
# cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 0 (v7l)
BogoMIPS    : 38.00
Features    : swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 evtstrm 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xd03
CPU revision    : 0

processor   : 1
(same)

processor   : 2
(same)    processor : 3

processor   : 3
(same)

Hardware    : Qualcomm Technologies, Inc MSM8916
Revision    : 81b0
Serial      : 01d8fa2100000000
Processor   : ARMv7 Processor rev 0 (v7l)
Device      : harpia
Radio       : US
MSM Hardware    : MSM8916
```

Questions:

- Is the kernel's lack of awareness of the `aes` feature bit a mistake, or limitation in the way that the kernel for this device has been built?
- Is AES hardware acceleration truly not available when running on an ARMv8-A CPU running a kernel built for ARMv7?
- Is it possible for userspace libraries or applications to take advantage of `aes` hardware support *despite* the fact that the kernel doesn't report its availability?

Comment: My guess it is a limitation of the kernel, just not knowing about ARMv8. The AES acceleration is provided by CPU instructions, so I presume it will be available none-the-less. `cpuinfo` shows the information by parsing the flags (that it knows of), I would recommend that you request and parse the flags yourself rather than relying on the kernel / cpuinfo.

Comment: Note that AES support is optional for ARMv8-A according to the ARM docs, but the MSM8916 410 SoC should support them.

Comment: [This article](https://community.arm.com/android-community/b/android/posts/runtime-detection-of-cpu-features-on-an-armv8-a-cpu) describes how to get the CPU flags in a portable way. I can confirm that you should be able to use AES instructions in 32-bit mode if the CPU does supports it.